# Approximation Multinomail distribution by binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

as i have heard i can approximate an

multinominal (aka polynomial) distribution by binomial distribution.

Now i am working on my thesis and need a reference in the literature 
or in an scientific article.

Has someone a reference (book, paper, article, ...) which covers this
or at least makes a reference on another one?

it would be really lovely

thanks
mel

Comment: hello . may i ask the forum again for their idea? thanks